# Scrolling with UITableView is slow

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView which displays fetched RSS dynamically, I have now customized the RSS to return the image name so that i can later on add a UIImageView to to every cell in the table which displays the image beside every cell, here is the code for adding the image

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL/%@",object.imageName]; //"object" is the returned Object from the RSS, so basically what i am doing is appending the image name to the path url.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

[cell addSubview:imageView];
[cell bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
```

so when i run my app the app runs slowly and even stops for a small amount of time, the reason for that is that i am loading all RSS imaged directly in this line `NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`

any solution for this problem ?

Thank you in advance

---

i actually thought of fetching the images in a separate thread,

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchImage = dispatch_queue_create("Fetching Image", NULL);
dispatch_async(fetchImage, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
});
dispatch_release(fetchImage);
```

but doing so wont allow me to use the variable "data" outside the queue.
any idea ?

Comment: load all of the images you will need into an array of some sort so you arent doing it on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL/%@",object.imageName]; 
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }); });
```

Comment: Did work perfectly, but i cannot tell what is the difference between moving a synchronous code do a separate thread or fetching images asynchronously, both have same results

Comment: @AlexyIbrahim the network connection should not put into the main thread , because it will cost lots of time and block the main thread (UI thread). so put it into background thread , when it loaded , then set the image on the main thread to refresh UI

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve your data asynchronously ! May be the use of a Open Source libraries will help you:

- [AFNetworking](http://www.afnetworking.com)
- [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) - not recommended

Or you can also use the `NSURLConnection` class with the asynchronous mode.

Comment: But bear in mind that ASINetworking has been officially abandoned for like two years at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The method `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` is synchronous: whenever you call it, it blocks the current thread (which is almost certainly your app's main thread) for as long as it takes to complete. This is *very bad*. Aside from making the UI feel janky, there's a watchdog process that will kill unresponsive apps.

You really, really want to use asynchronous network calls. Read up on `NSURLConnection`, but know, also, that there are many articles and libraries and samples out there on this exact subject: loading images asynchronously for display in a table view. Start with, maybe, AFNetworking's category on `UIImageView`, or maybe a library like SDWebImage.